# How to multiply two variables in constraints in Python (pulp package, optimization)?

Tags: python, variables, optimization, constraints, pulp

I have a question regarding the code below. In this problem we are trying to find a maximum value for x(i). Three variables are needed to find an optimal feasible solution, I won't bother you with the details. After defining the objective function, we continue with defining the constraints. The parameter d_ajs contains integer values for all combinations of a,j and s. The issue now is that multiplying the two variables returns the following error: **Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied**.

Can anyone help me out? What causes this error and how can it be solved?

Thanks in advance!

```
from pulp import *
prob = LpProblem("Model2", LpMaximize) 

# Variables
x = pd.Series(index=b_i.index)
for i in b_i.index:
    x[i] = LpVariable("x"+str(i), cat = 'Binary') 

y = pd.DataFrame(index=employees, columns=shifts)
for i in employees:
    for j in shifts:
        y.loc[i][j] = LpVariable("y"+str(i)+","+str(j), cat='Binary')

p = {}
for a in aeroplanes:
    p[a] = pd.DataFrame(index=employees, columns=shifts)
    for i in employees:
        for j in shifts:
            p[a].loc[i][j] = LpVariable("p"+str(a)+","+str(i)+","+str(j), cat='Binary')


# Objective 
obj = ''
for i in employees:
    obj += x[i]
prob += obj

# Constraints
s1 = time.time()
# Enough for the employees for the jobs
for a in aeroplanes:
    for j in shifts:
        for s in skills:
            nr = ""
            for i in employees:
                nr += y.loc[i][j]*p[a].loc[i][j]
            prob += nr >= d_ajs[a].loc[j][s]
```

Comment: The problem is, that the product of two variables is in general not linear and you are doing linear-programming. Start [here](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.de/2013/07/integer-variables-and-quadratic-terms.html).

Comment: What exact optimization problem are you trying to solve? What is the objective function? What are the constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Pulp Does not support non-linear programming and by multiplying two variables together you are making the problem non-linear.

I suggest that you think about your problem and see if there is any way to convert it to a linear problem, or use another tool that supports non-linear problems.